# Copying file to another folder are missing files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know why this code it doesn´t copy all files I said

The source folder have arround 8000 images, and I want to copy randomly 2719 images to another folder, but after run the script, the destiny folder has arround 2300 - 2400, so some images are missing.

```
import os, random
import shutil

src_dir = "C:/Users/X/Desktop/all/"
dst_dir = "C:/Users/X/Desktop/all1/"

file_list = os.listdir(src_dir)

for i in range(2719):
    a = random.choice(file_list)
    shutil.copy(src_dir + a, dst_dir + "/" + a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `random.choice` is that it can choose the same file multiple times. Shuffle the list and grab the first X items instead.

```
import os, random
import shutil

src_dir = "C:/Users/X/Desktop/all/"
dst_dir = "C:/Users/X/Desktop/all1/"

file_list = os.listdir(src_dir)
random.shuffle(file_list)

for a in file_list[:2719]:
    shutil.copy(src_dir + a, dst_dir + "/" + a)
```

Comment: IMHO, `random.samples` is better suited than shuffing the whole list and slicing for this example.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing 2719 random choices *with replacement* - i.e. items you've already picked can be picked again. To avoid doing replacement, use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

```
for a in random.sample(file_list, 2719):
    shutil.copy ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not removing chosen files from the list. If you don't remove them, they can be chosen twice. This is why you think the code misses some files. Try this:

```py
import os, random
import shutil

src_dir = "C:/Users/X/Desktop/all/"
dst_dir = "C:/Users/X/Desktop/all1/"

file_list = os.listdir(src_dir)

for i in range(2719):
    a = random.choice(file_list)
    file_list.remove(a)
    shutil.copy(src_dir + a, dst_dir + a)
```

Comment: The list have a limit?

Comment: What "limit" means for a list?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the line file_list.remove(a), why I need to remove choiced files from list to work?

Comment: If you dont remove it, it can be choiced twise. This why you think code misses some files.

Answer (score 1):

`random.choice` can have repeating value picked from `file_list`, so you need to check first whether this file has already been copied or not before copying. if you want to keep the files inside `src_dir` intact without removing them after copying, try this:

```
import os, random
import shutil

src_dir = "C:/Users/X/Desktop/all/"
dst_dir = "C:/Users/X/Desktop/all1/"

file_list = os.listdir(src_dir)
count = 0
while count!=2719:
    a = random.choice(file_list)
    if not os.path.exists(a):
        shutil.copy(src_dir + a, dst_dir + "/" + a)
        count+=1
```